# Passing var using jquery & ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, get

I am trying to pass the value of a  html  textbox form field to another .php file using jquery and ajax when the user defocuses that textbox. The textbox has the id "aircraftReg". I am using the code as follows...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#aircraftReg").blur(function() {
        var aircraftReg = $(this).value;
        $.get("searchDatabase.php?q=aircraftReg", function(data){                   
            // My function                 
        });  
    });
});
```

I think the problem lies in creating the var aircraftReg. I am attempting to assign its value to the text within the text box with id "aircraftReg".

Can anyone see what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change it like this:

```
 var aircraftReg = $(this).val();
 $.get("searchDatabase.php?q="+aircraftReg , function(data){                   
            // My function                 
        });
```

To get value of text field (or other input) there is `.val()` method in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `Url` because you are passing javascript `var` to url so it must me added with `+`.

```
var aircraftReg = $(this).val();
$.get("searchDatabase.php?q="+aircraftReg , function(data){                   
     //function logic goes here             
});
```

Comment: seems like your answer is exactly like mine? ;)

Comment: but some explanation must be there.

Comment: ok , good explanation is even more important than right code!

Comment: i not said explanation is even more important than right code but if we need to explain little for OP understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have passed `aircraftReg` as regular string not as a javascript variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#aircraftReg").blur(function() {
        var aircraftReg = $(this).value; //or $(this).val();
        $.get("searchDatabase.php?q="+ encodeURIComponent(aircraftReg), function(data){                   
            // My function                 
        });  
    });
});
```

Also, you have three encoding options:

`escape()` will not encode: `@*/+`

`encodeURI()` will not encode: `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`

`encodeURIComponent()` will not encode: `~!*()'`

Note: `escape()` function is non-ASCII, `encodeURI()` and `encodeURIComponent()` are **UTF-8** compatible.